# Meaning of a numerical ErrorMessage

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, com, atl

I am trying to interface with an OEM library. Everything worked on one computer but I am getting lots of problems on another computer.

I the code is throwing a COM exception but I can't figure out the meaning of a error code that doesn't have a `ErrorMessage();`

The code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <afx.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#import "MTBApi.tlb" named_guids //raw_interfaces_only
using namespace MTBApi; 
void DisplayError(_com_error* e)
{
    CString message;
    // if it is an application error thrown by .NET
    if (e->Error() >= 0x80041000)
    {
        IErrorInfo* info;
        BSTR msg;
        info = e->ErrorInfo();
        info->GetDescription(&msg);
        info->Release();
        message = CString(msg);
    }
    // other com errors
    else
    {
        message = e->ErrorMessage();
    }
    cout << "MTB Error: " <<  message <<":"<<(unsigned int) e->Error()<<  endl;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
    IMTBConnectionPtr m_MTBConnection;
    try
    {
        cout <<"1" << endl;
        HRESULT a = CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY);
        cout <<"2" << endl;
        m_MTBConnection = IMTBConnectionPtr(CLSID_MTBConnection);
        cout <<"3" << endl;
        m_MTBConnection->Close();
        cout <<"4" << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        cout <<"5" << endl;
    }
    catch(_com_error e)
    {
        DisplayError(&e);
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The runtime output

```
1
2
MTB Error: 00000000002205F8:2147746132

1
2
MTB Error: 00000000002205F8:2147746132

1
2
MTB Error: 00000000002205F8:2147746132

1
2
MTB Error: 00000000002205F8:2147746132
```

Rather Verbose Output from Dependency Walker

http://pastebin.com/7Y33z3Pj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << "MTB Error: " <<  message <<":"<<(unsigned int) e->Error()<<  endl;
```

`cout` isn't very good at displaying Unicode strings, it merely displays the string pointer value.  Not useful of course, use `wcout` instead.  And favor displaying the error code in hex.  0x80040154 is a *very* common COM error, "Class not registered".  Thousands of questions about it already, you just need to get the COM server registered properly.  Ask the vendor or author if you don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`00000000002205F8` looks like a memory pointer.  You are passing a `CString` to `cout`, which only accepts `char*` or `std::string` for string values.  Maybe the `CString` contains a Unicode string that is not being converted to Ansi correctly.  Also, when calling `IErrorInfo::GetDescription()`, you are leaking the returned `BSTR`.  You need to free it with `SysFreeString()` when you are done using it.

Error code `2147746132` (hex `0x80040154`) is Severity=FAIL, Facility=FACILITY_ITF, Code=340.  FACILITY_ITF typically means the error code is a custom error code defined by the interface that failed.  But in this case, `0x80040154` is also a standard error code: `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to rectify the error which you are getting then 
then issue is as @Remy pointed out , your com assembly is not registered in the machine you are currently executing your program rather in the other machine it got registered. Register the assembly (for eg COMAssembly.dll which is in C:\ drive) by running the following command in command prompt.

```
    regsvr32 c:\COMAssembly.dll
```

if its a C++ com assembly , if its a C# assembly register it by using command

```
    regasm c:\COMAssembly.dll
```

(where regasm can be run in a VS command prompt , otherwise if you are running in normal command prompt then you have to first call vsvars32.bat then call regasm)

Comment: You are going to get the OP into trouble with this.  There are many subtle details about proper registration, including using the *correct* version of Regsvr32, ensuring you are running elevated and providing the proper Regasm command line options.  Only post advice like this if you intend to cover the details.  In general, anybody that uses a COM server needs the vendor's deployment instructions.

Comment: @Hans : Yes  , i agree . Also depends on at runtime 32 bit app accessing 32 bit com dll and 64 bit app accessing 64 bit com dll.